# What happens if there are less calls than the number in permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState during the maxWaitDurationInHalfOpenState?

Tags: circuit-breaker, resilience4j

did not find this information elsewhere in the documentation, what happens if there are less calls than the number in permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState during the maxWaitDurationInHalfOpenState? does it calculate failure rate from the made calls or it goes back to open state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone will be searcing for this, tested it, so if it does not reach the permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState until maxWaitDurationInHalfOpenState is over, the circuit breaker goes back to open state.